# Using an environment variable in a file docker container

Tags: bash, docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-statefulset

I am setting an environment variable in a docker container whose value I receive at run time.

```
  env:
    - name: POD_INFO
      value: {{ Values.resolved_when_the_container_starts }}
```

I want to use this value inside an XML file. Is there a way I can do this ?

Something like

```
<property>
   <name>pod.info</name>
   <value>this place should pick up the value from that environment variable</value>
</property>
```

Comment: Is this actually a Kubernetes question?  Helm?  Where does the XML file come from?  (Could you use a Helm template to create it in a Kubernetes ConfigMap object?)

Comment: it seems like this is helm, so the XML is inside the container?

Comment: I wanted to give as much context as possible. As such I put in the kubernetes tag.

@DavidMaze. CM is not an option here, since I am getting POD_INFO when the container starts up. Think of it as a concatenated string between POD_HOST(which is a kubernetes standard POD_HOST ) and then some code that creates a namespace and service . So POD_INFO would be POD_HOST+Namespace+service name. And namespace is randomly generated name. As such I cant hardcode it into a configmap.

Comment: @paltaa , Yes, its a helm template. So the XML is inside the container.

Answer (score 0):

Neither Kubernetes nor Helm provide a way to template ConfigMaps or any other files. What you're probably looking for is [init container](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/), which starts before your container and which can execute any custom script you want. Then, you can modify the configuration file with your environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

You could use envsubst and call it in your `entrypoint.sh` script.  You will have to define your variable first and then substitute them with `envsubst`.

[kminehart](https://github.com/kminehart) explaines very well how `envsubst` works in one of the github [cases](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/52787#issuecomment-355694085).

```
# mytemplate.tmpl  
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1  
kind: Deployment  
# ...  
architecture: ${GOOS}
```

```
GOOS=amd64 envsubst < mytemplate.tmpl > mydeployment.yaml
```

```
# mydeployment.yaml  
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1  
kind: Deployment  
# ...  
architecture: amd64
```

Another way of env substition is `sed`. [Here](https://zhu45.org/posts/2016/Dec/21/environment-variable-substitution-using-sed/) is  a good article that shows how it works.

```
sed -i -g "s/[target_expression]/[replace_expression/g" <file>
```